# My win 7 ultimate computer has been professionally hijacked and configured to limit local access

Tags: windows-7

My win 7 ultimate computer has been professionally hijacked and configured to limit local access, windows, tools, etc. I cannot change their settings to take back control of my home computer.

They use accounts above Admin so as to lock me out to change them.

Services are added that I don't need, password protected with their accounts and dependencies are changed so if you can turn off a service the hijack depends on it will turn off other services you must have.

They also grey out the ability to change some of the services. So you cannot remove their account or turn it off.

The network is hijacked and encrypted and sent usually ip v6 sometimes through my ip4 port.

If you delete the network settings it has to reboot and if you reboot it goes back to the hijack settings.

Is there a script that could put win 7 ult back in my control and delete the services that a stand alone home computer not a client or server computer or on any group need that would prevent this hijack.

A script that could put all settings and services back to original default and delete any startup or autorun scripts that could reconfigure the system would help.

Ideally a script to set the system for use as a home computer will ALL of the un-needed services uninstalled or locked off.

Anyone have any such configuration script that would free my computer?

Comment: Have you tried booting in safe mode?  If so, could you please say what effect this had, if any?

Comment: Why waste time trying to fix this... backup your important files and re-install Windows... It'll take a few hours to get up and have your programs re-installed but you'll have a clean system...

Answer (score 0):

The link Hennes provided has some great information, here are your options in a nutshell.

Before doing any of them,  back up all your important files to an external drive.

(In order from easy to hard)

1. Use a system image or restore point to go back to before the problem began.
2. Re-install Windows (As Big Chris suggested)
3. Take out your hard drive, put it in a computer with a clean OS and attempt to de-bug it from there. (Do not boot from your drive when putting it in another computer)

Unless you have a compelling reason to not want to do a fresh install, take options one or two.  If you are worried you might forget some files, backup your infected drive if you must so you know the files are there should you realize you missed something.

Option three will chew up your time and in the end, you will never know if you got everything off there.